# Time format passing a date to function instead of Time in VBA

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, variables, timer

The On Open function of the form sets the value of my variable, then passes it to the Form Timer. Stepping through it formats the time correctly in the on open, but once it's passed to the form timer function it changes to a date and doesn't display correctly.

```
Dim timeRemaining As Date

 
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    timeRemaining = Format(900, "Short Time")
    
    
End Sub
 
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1
    lblTimer.Caption = "You will be logged out in " & vbCrLf & timeRemaining & " second"
    If timeRemaining > 1 Then
        lblTimer.Caption = lblTimer.Caption & "s."
    End If
    DoEvents
    If timeRemaining = 0 Then
        'shut down
        Do While Forms.Count > 0
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Forms(0).Name, acSaveYes
        Loop
        
        Do While Reports.Count > 0
            DoCmd.Close acReport, Forms(0).Name, acSaveYes
        Loop

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @KostasK. when I try to declare it as time, it gives me a user defined error.

Comment: Why not use `Dim timeRemaining As long`? And you just format the label

Comment: @Storax I get a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the TimerInterval is set to 1000 ms for your form because do not mention that at all. Anyway, based on your code you have to set it to 1000ms otherwise you have to change the line `timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1` accordingly.

My code would look like that

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Dim timeRemaining As Long

 
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    timeRemaining = 900
End Sub
 
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1        
    lblTimer.Caption = "You will be logged out in " & vbCrLf & _
                    Int(timeRemaining / 60) & " minuntes " & timeRemaining - Int(timeRemaining / 60) * 60 & " seconds"
    If timeRemaining > 1 Then
        lblTimer.Caption = lblTimer.Caption & "s."
    End If
    DoEvents
    If timeRemaining = 0 Then
        'shut down
        Do While Forms.Count > 0
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Forms(0).Name, acSaveYes
        Loop
        
        Do While Reports.Count > 0
            DoCmd.Close acReport, Forms(0).Name, acSaveYes
        Loop

    End If
End Sub
```

Improved code would do the calculations in an extra line

Answer (score 1):

First, set the *TimerInterval* property to 1000. That is milliseconds, thus 1 second.

Next, modify like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    
    timeRemaining = TimeSerial(0, 0, 900)    
    
End Sub

 
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    timeRemaining = DateAdd("s", -1, timeRemaining)

    lblTimer.Caption = "You will be logged out in " & vbCrLf & timeRemaining & " second"
    If timeRemaining > TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) Then
        lblTimer.Caption = lblTimer.Caption & "s."
    End If
    
    DoEvents
    
    If timeRemaining <= 0 Then
        'shut down
        Do While Forms.Count > 0
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Forms(0).Name, acSaveYes
        Loop
        
        Do While Reports.Count > 0
            DoCmd.Close acReport, Forms(0).Name, acSaveYes
        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```